# Cisco 6500 chassis modules color edge

Tags: switch, hardware

The modules for the Cisco 6500-series switches have a color band on the right edge. The most common I've seen are magenta (or an occasional purple) on Ethernet modules and aqua on supervisors. Are there other colors? What do the colors actually represent? I've looked at the documentation for several modules and the "Catalyst 6500 Series Switch Module Installation Guide" (which has info about all of the LEDs) but haven't found any reference to the color.

Thanks.

Comment: Those switches have a passive backplane. So the capabilities of the backplane are set by the supervisor card(s). The colour tabs indicate that a module is designed to work with a supervisor of that same colour. There's mostly backward compatibility but not forward compatibility.

Comment: @vk5tu I don't think that's right. For example, the Sup 2 or 720, which work on the 6500, is turquoise, but most of the line cards are purple. The Sup 2T requires a 6500E but is also turquoise, and most of its compatible line cards are also purple.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: @RonMaupin, not really, but perhaps there isn't anything definitive. No one has answered if there are other colors or what they represent other than the same observances I've had.

Answer (score 3):

In general, supervisors (Sup720p, Sup2T) and service modules (FWSM, WLSM, ACE) are coloured cyan.  Line cards (providing switch connectivity) are coloured magenta.

Some of the older cards providing content switching can also be coloured magenta.

Comment: That's what I've observed too, but I couldn't find anything definitive. Are there other colors? What do the colors actually represent?

Comment: I don't think they have any special significance except magenta = line card, cyan = supervisor or services module.  They don't relate to the slots they can be in stalled in.  Supervisors only can be installed in certain slots (5&6 on 6500) and line cards or service modules can be installed in any other slot.  The only other restriction is that some line cards requiring higher backplane bandwidth can only be installed in certain slots on some chassis.  As you can see the slot location doesn't relate to colour